# How can I parse 2 xml tag into 1 struct in go?

Tags: xml, go, encoding

I have 2 tag  called  and  but I must parse them same struct. Both have same things but in different tags I have to mix them into another xml.

```
<Products>
  <Product_name>TOY</Product_name>
<\Products>

<Goods>
  <Goods_name>TOY</Goods_name>
<\Goods>
```

I tried like this:

```
type Products struct {
XMLName  xml.Name  `xml:"Products,Goods"`
Products []Product `xml:"Product"`}
```

But i wont work. Can you help me?

Comment: Make a [mcve] and include the XML code.

Comment: heu just in case this is `</Product_name>` not `<\Product_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it is hard to provide a good answer.

I don't know the size of your xml, and if you need to parse only some tags or the entire file.

I am working with very huge xml file, to limit the memory consumption I use [decoder.RawToken](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder.RawToken) this avoid to check if the closing tag is the one matching the opening one.
If you need to handle xml on a very specific way you can parse it and get only the data you need.

Here an example creating a slice of Product

You can find it here:
https://play.golang.org/p/a4VirqzXjLP

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Product struct {
    name  string
    other int
}

func main() {
    str := strings.NewReader("<Products>\n<Product_name>TOYP</Product_name>\n</Products>\n\n<Goods>\n<Goods_name>TOYG</Goods_name>\n</Goods>")
    fmt.Println(str)
    var products []Product
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(str)
    for {
        t, err := decoder.RawToken()
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        var inElement string
        switch se := t.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            inElement = strings.TrimSpace(se.Name.Local)
            switch inElement {
            case "Product_name":
                fallthrough
            case "Goods_name":
                t, err := decoder.RawToken()
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("Err %v\n", err)
                    break
                }
                switch element := t.(type) {
                case xml.CharData:
                    products = append(products, Product{name: string(element)})
                default:
                    fmt.Println("should not happen")
                    continue
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(products)

}
```

Output:

```
&{<Products>
<Product_name>TOYP</Product_name>
</Products>

<Goods>
<Goods_name>TOYG</Goods_name>
</Goods> 0 -1}
[{TOYP 0} {TOYG 0}]
```